# Case-insensitive string comparison on VS2010 - playing with #if defined statements for each version of VS

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am converting some old code to a Visual Studio 2010 project and the following is giving me errors...

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1200 || defined __BORLANDC__
#define cv_stricmp stricmp
#define cv_strnicmp strnicmp
#if defined WINCE
#define strdup _strdup
#define stricmp _stricmp
#endif
#elif defined __GNUC__ || defined __sun
#define cv_stricmp strcasecmp
#define cv_strnicmp strncasecmp
#else
#error Do not know how to make case-insensitive string comparison on this platform
#endif
```

I'm not sure how to adopt these statements for Visual Studio 2010.  How could I do this?

Comment: Which errors are you getting? "Do not know how to make..." or something else?

Comment: Whenever you ask questions regarding compiler errors, always **make sure to post the exact error message** that you receive.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't mean the `#error` is hit, because that wouldn't happen with VC 2010.

If you mean the deprecation warnings, try using `_stricmp` and `_strnicmp` instead:

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1200 || defined __BORLANDC__
    #if _MSC_VER >= 1400
        #define cv_stricmp _stricmp
        #define cv_strnicmp _strnicmp
    #else
        #define cv_stricmp stricmp
        #define cv_strnicmp strnicmp
`   #endif
    #if defined WINCE
        #define strdup _strdup
        #define stricmp _stricmp
    #endif
#elif defined __GNUC__ || defined __sun
    #define cv_stricmp strcasecmp
    #define cv_strnicmp strncasecmp
#else
    #error Do not know how to make case-insensitive string comparison on this platform
#endif
```